# Button overlapping header

Tags: html, css

The header I've made keeps getting overlapped by the button that I placed in front of the image.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t6Pp.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKA8I.png)

I feel like this is happening due to the outer_header position: fixed but I cannot seem to find an alternative that will allow it to overlap the button. And I am not sure why it doesn't overlap the other content.

My assumption is that its because the button's position is absolute but I need that to be able to move to the button on top of the image.

```css
.outer_header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 98%;
 padding:20px;
 top:0;
 background-color: #e6c300;
}

.header {
 background-color: #333;
 position: sticky;
 top:0;
}

.header * {
 display: inline;
}

.active{
 background-color: grey;
}

.Navigation a{
 border-style: solid;
   border-color:grey;
   background-clip: padding-box;
   background-color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}
.Navigation a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
 border-color:black;
}

#search_bar {
 padding:6px;
 margin-top: 8px;
   font-size: 15px;
   border: none;
}

.search-icon, .add_cart{
 padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
   margin-right: 16px;
   background: #ddd;
   font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.add_cart {
   background: black;
}

#banner {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 90px;
}


#Banner_btn {
 position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 78.25%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 24px 16px 24px 16px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;

}

#Banner_btn:hover {
 background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a z-index to your header

```
.header {
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

and if that doesn't work, also add a lower z-index to #Banner_btn, eg:

```
#Banner_btn { z-index: 5; }
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! The z-index seems very useful in this regard. Thank you so much.